# NumericUpDown Value turns to 0 when it is set as a float

Tags: c#, floating-point, int, numeric

So resizeWidth and resizeHeight are numericUpDown controls in this following code.
Also, tempBitmapW and tempBitmapH are both floats.

```
float rW = (float)resizeWidth.Value;
float rH = (float)resizeHeight.Value;
rH = (float)Math.Truncate(tempBitmapH * ((float)rW / tempBitmapW));
int rsW = (int)rW;
int rsH = (int)rH;
resizeWidth.Value = rsW;
resizeHeight.Value = rsH;
```

Now when I debug this, rsW and rsH and rW and rH do not read as 0, none of them.
But for some reason the numericUpDown controls throw an error as the Value 0 is out side the Minimum/Maximum range (the minimum is set to 1), so basically it is reading it as 0.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: What are the original values of tempBitmapH, resizeWidth.Value and resizeHeight.Value?

Comment: Are you certain that rsW and rsH are bigger than 0? This is not a normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You just dont understand correctly how casts work. 
Because of the way you are casting floats to int, you are getting 0. The float value might be 0.42 but that will cast to 0 in an integer.

You should check how casts work in detail, that will probably solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I found the problem, I'm not sure if you are basically saying this, but because this takes place each time one of the numericUpDown's value changes, it just keeps firing the other when it changes it at the end, so it just keeps reducing it until it reaches 0. I have fixed the problem now so it only fires when the value is manually changed.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on squelos' answer- it sounds like perhaps the moment when you're looking at the values in the debugger and the moment when the exception is being thrown are two different moments in time. If you're getting an exception saying the value is zero- it's probably because the value is zero.

The **reason** it might become zero is because the cast from float to int always rounds down to the nearest integer.